# Write a hello world GUI program that closes itself after three seconds

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output, hello-world

Please read the rules, **and the bold areas as well**.

Write a program in any language, so long as it has GUI support for a window system (cannot be text-consoles, etc., and must be a GUI/toolkit/window).

The program must say hello world in any manner (splash image, menu bar, status bar, title, video, message box, other widget stuff, etc.), **so long as a GUI-compliant window appears and shows this text for three seconds**. The person who can code this in the least amount of code used, counted in bytes, will take the cake.

Comment: The comments here have degraded into a pointless argument. Please refrain from extended discussion in the comments; if necessary, you may use [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) instead. All comments have been purged.

Comment: It doesn't matter where the argument came from - all users should avoid participating in disputes that are clearly noise or going nowhere.

Comment: Does it have to be "Hello world" or can it be "Hello_world"?

Comment: Also, must it exit gracefully?

Comment: you don't specify how the program has to be run? for instance does it have to be started up by itself or can it be something loaded up in a already running environment?

Comment: So what's the etiquette for accepting answers on code golfing questions? This question has been open for ~ four months.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Hello, World!"](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55422/hello-world)

Comment: Does the GUI window need to close, or is it enough that the words 'hello world' are replaced?

Comment: Is outputting "hllowrld" acceptable?

Answer (score 29):

## Unix shell, 31 characters

```
xmessage -timeout 3 hello world
```

[image: message "hello world" with button "okay"]

This program requires the [xmessage(1)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=xmessage&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=OpenBSD+Current&arch=i386&format=html) utility from X.Org. It uses the traditional black-and-white X Athena Widgets (Xaw).

Comment: Grrr...I was going to post one using `timeout` and `zenity` but it was longer...

Comment: @BenjiWiebe There is a `zenity` answer by n.1 at http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28451/4065

Comment: You can save 1 byte: timeout 3 xmessage hello world

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson I can't do that, because my machine has no `timeout` command. Maybe someone else can post a new answer that uses it?

Answer (score 24):

## Shell and gedit - 27 characters

```bash
timeout 3 gedit Hello World
```

> [image]

If Hello World needs to be displayed as a single string, then its **28** characters:

```bash
timeout 3 gedit Hello\ World
```

`timeout` utility runs a command for the duration specified. It ensures that gedit runs for 3 seconds, assuming minimal startup time.

Any editor can be used in place of `gedit`. If a shorter named editor is used like `gvim`, the length can be reduced by 1 or more characters.

<sub>Using an editor initially thought of by [user80551](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28425/8395).</sub>

Comment: Escape the space, use `Hello\ World`

Comment: @user80551 The question requires "Hello World" to be displayed in *any manner*, so that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Technically, that would make this `Hello <space> <close icon> <Document icon> World`

Comment: Can you confirm if `kate` would work instead of `gedit`?

Comment: @user80551 Dont have KDE installed, but going by [Kate's man page](http://www.kate-editor.org/doc/fundamentals.html), there doesnt seem to be any reason why it shouldn't work.

Comment: @user80551: It does work in `kate`, although the display [looks a bit different](http://i.stack.imgur.com/W2EJg.png).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I think that's because it's creating two separate documents. Did you escape the space i.e. `Hello\ World` instead of `Hello World`?

Comment: @user80551: No I did not. Obviously, with an escaped space it would appear on one line (but then you lose the one-char advantage over `gedit`).

Answer (score 20):

## Applescript, 45 bytes:

Not often Applescript is one of the shorter answers:

```
display alert "hello world" giving up after 3
```

Paste into the Applescript Editor and run, or run using `osascript` at the command line:

```
osascript -e 'display alert "hello world" giving up after 3'
```

[image]

Answer (score 17):

## HTML+Javascript, <strike>73</strike> 60 characters

```html
<script>setTimeout("open('','_self','');close()",3e3)</script>Hello world
```

This works in Chrome, but may not be portable to other browsers.

Suggestions from the comments take this further:

```
<body onload=open('',name=setTimeout(close,3e3))>Hello world
```

Comment: That's a lot of golfing I saw. I saw this go from `108` chars down to `73`. Suddenly, the whole code is visible.

Comment: @Quincunx: You missed the first few iterations then. :)

Comment: That's because I was busy posting my own code. :-)

Comment: For some reason, I see the string for much longer than 3 seconds (it doesn't close).

Comment: I tried in Firefox and IE and they both have stronger restrictions on web pages closing their own windows.

Comment: I'm using chrome. I also tried jsfiddle.

Comment: `<body onload=open('','_self'),setTimeout(close,3e3)>Hello world` seems to save a few more characters.

Comment: -1 more byte from @Ventero 's version: `<body onload=open('',name=0),setTimeout(close,3e3)>Hello world`

Comment: You have an edit suggestion from user3082537: save two chars by `<body onload=open('',name=setTimeout(close,3e3))>Hello world`

Comment: Can't you just do `<body onload=setTimeout(close,3e3))>Hello world` or am I missing something here?

Comment: @Danny Only windows that have been explicitly opened with `open` can be closed by calling `close` on them.

Comment: @Ventero oh. It worked for me in IE9 and Chrome. Guess they aren't following the rules.

Comment: @Danny It doesn't work in Chrome for me (after removing the extra `)`): `Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.`.

Comment: @Ventero odd, I'm on `35.0.1916.114 m` and it works. Maybe I have a setting somewhere that is allowing it.

Answer (score 16):

### shell script, 31

Not sure whether it qualifies. Requires `notify-send`. Works at least on Ubuntu 12.04.

```
notify-send -t 3000 Hello world
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Probably not since it isn't a GUI compliant ***window***. Unfortunately, using `zenity` is much longer.

Comment: Its 34 chars with gedit - http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28425/8766

Comment: I believe that a window with no window decorations is still a window. Here in Enlightenment, the notification also has an X button to close it (but no other window decorations).

Answer (score 12):

### shell + gedit / geany, 34

```bash
gedit Hello\ World&sleep 3;kill $!
```

[image: Hello World in gedit]

This assumes that gedit pops up instantly since the 3 seconds are counted from the start of issuing the command. Could be smaller if there's a GUI text editor shorter than `gedit`.

`geany` works too for the same number of chars, just `s/gedit/geany/g`

[image: Hello World in geany]

EDIT: Using `timeout` is shorter. https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28477/8766

EDIT2: Can anyone confirm if this works with `kate` ?

---

### meld , 32

If exactly `Hello World` is not required, then `meld` can be used.

```bash
meld Hello World&sleep 3;kill $!
```

[image: Hello : World - Meld]

Comment: Nice idea, `gedit` tries to open a file with this name even if there's no file.

Comment: If you use `gvim` it will need only **33** chars

Comment: Its 27 chars using `timeout` http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28477/8395

Comment: @avall   For some weird reason, the actually gvim process is getting started after 3 PIDs so it isn't getting killed. See http://pastebin.com/5PVgf9fm

Comment: Good answer. I tried Kate,it gives error: QDBusConnection.

Comment: `reboot` saves a character compared to `kill $!`

Comment: @Daniel `halt` would be shorter but I don't know if being destructive is allowed. Also, it requires root permissions so we either need to assume that we are root or use `sudo` which costs more (and needs the user to type the password).

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to be humorous.  I was assuming the user has root permissions.

Comment: @Daniel No need to be sorry, this site is based on the most evil devious twisting of the rules to make your code shorter.

Answer (score 7):

### VBScript, 58

```vb
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Popup"Hello world",3
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 6):

### Python (pygame), 87

```py
import pygame.display as d,time
d.set_mode()
d.set_caption('Hello world')
time.sleep(3)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Not working on OSX, doesn't show window...

Comment: @BritishColour it should, perhaps it's too small? Try changing the size to `[999,999]`

Comment: Still not working, the window isn't even appearing...

Comment: @BritishColour Well it definitely works for me. See [here](https://i.imgur.com/hknh2GS.gif). Perhaps it was showing up at the background or something?

Comment: What does the `d.set_mode([200,9])` do? If it is just to make the window big enough, I don't think it is necessary (provided a window appears).

Comment: @Quincunx `set_mode` is needed to make the window appear. But it turns out the dimensions are not needed. Thanks.

Comment: It's interesting how our code is basically identical, but uses a different module. `tkinter` turns out to be shorter.

Comment: Use `from pygame.display import *`

Answer (score 6):

### Tcl - 32 bytes

I noticed that some of these submissions, like the shell or javascript ones, allow you to type the code into the console. If that's the case I can shorten it to:

```
wm ti . hello\ world;af 3000 exi
```

Must be typed into the console **after** running wish. Meaning, run `wish` without arguments which will give you a REPL console and then type the code above. This makes use of the fact that tcl can be lenient and autocomplete command/function names but only in interactive mode. So that `af` actually exectues the `after` command and `exi` executes `exit`. I wanted to use `ex` but my system has the `ex` editor installed.

---

### Original submission - 36 bytes

```
wm ti . hello\ world;after 3000 exit
```

Run using `wish` instead of `tclsh`.

Answer (score 5):

### <s>52</s> 51 chars with Mathematica

(Hope it counts as a GUI-compliant.)

```
NotebookClose/@{CreateDialog@"Hello world",Pause@3}
```

[image: Mathematica GUI Golf code]

Answer (score 4):

## Java, 136 bytes

```java
class F{public static void main(String[]a)throws Exception{new java.awt.Frame("Hello World").show();Thread.sleep(3000);System.exit(0);}}
```

Displays the message `Hello World` as the title of a frame. After `3` seconds, the program closes.

Looks like this:

[image]

Drag it bigger:

[image]

---

Expanded code (ie readable):

```java
class F {

    public static void main(String[] a) throws Exception {
        new java.awt.Frame("Hello World").show();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

Comment: You can use `enum` instead of `class` to save another character.

Comment: @Riking it doesn't work.

Comment: Really? I could've sworn I actually used that once... Dang.

Comment: @Riking http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/tips-for-golfing-in-java#comment59425_6689

Answer (score 4):

### R, 44

```r
x11(ti="Hello World");Sys.sleep(3);dev.off()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

### PowerShell - <strike>63</strike> 52

```
(new-object -c wscript.shell).popup('Hello World',3)
```

Answer (score 4):

## GTK+, <del>47</del> 45

```bash
zenity --info --text=Hello\ World --timeout=3
```

[image: Hello World]

---

Old version (score 47):

```bash
zenity --info --title="Hello World" --timeout=3
```

[image: Hello World]

For some reason, zenity display a text which can be translated as *All update are done*.

Comment: Just to add some extra info, *All updates are complete.* is what I get in English.

Comment: You can reduce one character by changing `--title` to `--text`

Comment: You can change `"Hello World"` to `Hello\ World`

Comment: Thanks AsheeshR and kernigh, I have 2 less characters with your help.

Answer (score 4):

## Visual FoxPro - 23 characters

```
WAIT"hello world"TIME 3
```

[image: Hello world in VFP]

This abuses the fact that VFP allows to not to put a space between the string to be printed (which I just discovered) and that it allows to shorten every keyword to up to its first 4 characters.

Ungolfed version:

```
WAIT "hello world" TIMEOUT 3
```

Answer (score 4):

### Batch (24)

```
msg/time:3 * hello world
```

Tested on Windows 7, but should work on any NT-based version of Windows, assuming you have MSG.EXE in your System32 folder.

EDIT: Apparently MSG.EXE is not available by default on home versions of Windows. On Windows 7, for example, this is only available in the Ultimate or Business editions. However, you can copy the file over to your System32 folder and get it to work. (You must also copy over the appropriate MSG.EXE.MUI file to get proper error messages, but my "script" works without them.)

You have to install software for most of these other responses to work, too, so I don't think that should be a disqualifier.

Comment: Why won't this call a program named `time:3` in a folder called `msg` in the current directory?

Comment: @cat Windows uses ``\``.

Comment: @jimmy wow that was a year ago. i'm just used to writing / on all platforms now oops

Comment: @jimmy23013 But Windows supports `/` too

Comment: @MilkyWay90 Windows supports `/` in some places, but in `cmd`, `/xxx` is interpreted as an argument.

Answer (score 3):

### C, 151 characters

```cpp
#include<allegro.h>
main(){textout_ex(screen,font,"Hello World",0,0,7,set_gfx_mode('SAFE',8,8,install_timer(),
allegro_init()));rest(3e3);}END_OF_MAIN()
```

Not the smallest answer. I like it though.

Comment: Good job.                  &#32&#32&#32&#32

Comment: How does that even compile? `'SAFE'` isn't a single char.

Comment: @heinrich5991 SAFE is likely defined in allegro.h as a single character.

Comment: @AdamDavis C evaluates macros in character constants?

Comment: No macro, it's really just a 32-bit integer written as four bytes in what's called multi-character constant notation, a too-clever-for-its-own-good way to write four-byte tag strings. Apple used it for file type magic numbers once. Compilers nowadays support it but emit a warning. [Example for nonbelievers](https://gist.github.com/wandernauta/86d070e3565cec8e7d02)

Answer (score 3):

## C# <strike>101</strike> 151

This will for sure not be the shortest answer (since there are already other good answers being way shorter) but codegolf.SE needs a lot more C# contributions in my opinion!

```cs
using t=System.Threading;class P{static void Main(){using(t.Tasks.Task.Run(()=>System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("hello world"))){t.Thread.Sleep(3000);}}}
```

## C# 121

An alternative based on [Bob's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28480/21478), but with WPF instead of WinForms:

```cs
class P{static void Main(){new System.Windows.Window(){Title="hello world"}.Show();System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);}}
```

Saves 3 characters thanks to the shorter namespace ...

Comment: You need to include the `using` declarations in the character count. Alternatively, you could leave them out but then you'd have to do things like `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show` (slightly fewer characters if it's only a single use). As your code currently is, it won't compile or run.

Comment: Well, I just assumed it was not neccesary because I see a lot of answers in C, C++, C#, Java etc without any using/imports/whatever. I will edit it, though. BTW, is there some explicit rule on this? Sure it would compile and run with the right compile settings and/or compiler. (e. g. resolving using directives on compile time, as long as they can be resolved distinct)

Comment: The consensus seems to be that you need to: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/383/should-imports-includes-count-in-golf http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19/should-non-standard-compiler-flags-be-included-in-character-counts http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84/shebangs-yes-or-no

Comment: It is a little grey - for example, I had to add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms.dll`, which is part of the msbuild config/the compile command line. However, the general consensus seems to be that when a full program is requested, `using`/`import`/`#include`/etc. where necessary for the code to compile and run are required, and attempting to use compiler command line tricks to dodge that is bad.

Comment: I will keep that in mind. Thank you for the references.

Answer (score 3):

### bash + ImageMagick (36 bytes)

```
timeout 3 display label:Hello\ world
```

Tested on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and on Fedora 20.

Nicer-looking, but 10 bytes larger:

```
timeout 3 display -size 800 label:Hello\ world
```

Answer (score 3):

### CMD / Batch - 33 Bytes

I believe the window that the Windows CMD terminal runs in counts as GUI compliant.

```
start "Hello world" cmd /csleep 3
```

If you don't have the `sleep` command on your system - then you can use `timeout` which comes default in Windows 7. For two more bytes.

```
start "Hello world" cmd /ctimeout 3
```

Starts a new CMD window with the title "Hello World" (**NOT** displayed in the terminal itself, but as the title of the GUI window that the terminal runs in), this window will close as soon as all parsed commands have executed - so after `sleep 3` or `timeout 3` has completed.

The window looks like this -

[image: Bloke]

Note; `start` runs the given commands in a new window - not the window that you are running the above commands from.

Comment: Changing it to `cmd "Hello world" cmd /ctimeout 3` puts Hello world in the title bar for 3 seconds, but that probably doesn't count.

Comment: I wouldn't think it does, because it doesn't spawn a new window. The question says **a GUI-compliant window appears** (appears being the key word), implying that it has to display a new window. Good idea though.

Comment: `start "Hello world"` You sir, are a genius.

Answer (score 3):

## [Autohotkey](https://autohotkey.com/), 22 Bytes

```
msgbox,,hello world,,3
```

Ahk's [msgbox](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MsgBox.htm) is pretty powerful and has a built-in timeout option.

[image: msgbox]

Comment: 1 year late lol

Answer (score 3):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 49 bytes

```
view[text"hello world"rate 0:0:3 on-time[unview]]
```

Answer (score 2):

### APL (40)

```
X.Close⊣⎕DL 3⊣'X'⎕WC'Form' 'Hello World'
```

Comment: 39: `X.Close⊣⎕DL⍴⍕'X'⎕WC'Form' 'Hello World'`

Answer (score 2):

### Lua + LÖVE, 67 bytes

```
l=love l.window.setTitle"hello world"l.timer.sleep(3)l.event.quit()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Perl 5, 47

Using [Perl/Tk](http://search.cpan.org/~srezic/Tk-804.032/Tk.pod):

```bash
perl -MTk -e'alarm 3;tkinit-title,"Hello World!";MainLoop'
#     123    45678901234567890123456789012345678901234567
```

Comment: It seems that the Tk module is required.

Comment: Yes, of course you need *some* GUI toolkit. I choose Tk because of tkinit().

Comment: I count 44 bytes. Are you counting the `-MTk` flag as well?

Comment: @slebetman Yes I count that as 3 chars, I added the count to the post.

Comment: @Matthias: maybe you should add it to the title language as *Perl 5 + Tk*. I tested it and was surprised to see that Perl 5 is not sufficient to run it.

Comment: @n.1 I added it below the title with a link to the CPAN documentation of the Tk module. None of the perl core modules is a GUI module, therefore you always have to install external modules. Sorry, this was clear to me (as I am working with perl quite often), but you are right, it is surprising for those who work in other languages.

Answer (score 2):

## Perl on Windows (56)

```
use Win32;fork?kill+sleep+3,$$:Win32'MsgBox"Hello World"
```

Comment: Use '-MWin32' to save four bytes

Answer (score 2):

## Processing, 77

```java
int x=millis();void draw(){text("Hello world",0,9);if(millis()>x+3e3)exit();}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

**Edit 1:** Y position of the text can be 9 instead of 10, like noted by @ace.

**Edit 2:** 3000 can be represented as 3e3 to shave one character off, also noted by @ace

Comment: Using 9 for Y position instead of 10 works for me.

Comment: Just edited the code. Thanks!

Comment: Just noticed you can use `3e3` instead of `3000` to save one more char

Answer (score 2):

## QML - 98 bytes

Here's the code. Works on all supported platforms (including Android and iOS):

```
import QtQuick 1.0;Text{text:"Hello world";Timer{interval:3000;onTriggered:Qt.quit();running:1>0}}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know QML, but can you change `true` into `1` or `1>0`?

Comment: @ace qml wants boolean, so 1 didn't work for me, but as you suggested, 1>0 works fine  thanks a bunch, squeezed one more byte 

Answer (score 2):

## Rebol View (r3gui), 49

```
view/no-wait[title"hello world"]wait 3 unview/all
```

[image: "hello world" from Rebol 3 View]

Ungolfed:

```
view/no-wait [title "hello world"]
wait 3
unview/all
```

Answer (score 2):

## PowerShell, <strike>72</strike> 49

```
saps -pa notepad "Hello World"|%{sleep 3;kill $_}
```

[image]

Thanks to @joey for continued golfing

Comment: `saps -pa notepad "Hello World"|%{sleep 3;kill $_}` would be quite a bit shorter.

Answer (score 2):

#### Python with turtle module (<strike>69</strike> 66 bytes)

```
import turtle as t,time
t.title("Hello World")
t.fd(1)
time.sleep(3)
```

Note that if you run this in an interactive console, you don't need the `t.fd(9)` line. However, for some reason when running this non-interactively, the title doesn't change unless you run the extra line.

#### Edit (66 bytes)

```
import turtle as t
t.title("Hello World")
t.ontimer(t.fd(1),3000)
```

Answer (score 2):

## PureBasic, 91 chars

Okay, it's not the shortest, it will never win, but I still gotta support my favourite BASIC dialect :-)

```
OpenWindow(0,9,9,99,99,"")
TextGadget(0,0,0,99,99,"Hello World")
Delay(3000)
CloseWindow(0)
```

[image: Hello World picture]

Answer (score 2):

## Java, 153 bytes

```
interface a{static void main(String[]A){new Thread(()->javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("Hello world")).start();Thread.sleep(3000);throw null;}}
```

Points to `null` three seconds after popping up a <strike>quite ugly</strike> window with the text "Hello world" on it.

Answer (score 2):

## SmileBASIC, 23 bytes

```
DIALOG"hello world",,,3
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog APL)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 36 bytes

```apl
⎕EX(⎕DL 3)⊢⎕A⎕WC'Form' 'hello world'
```

`⎕A`  uppercase **A**lphabet (the only legal name which can be written with two characters)

`⎕WC` **W**indow **C**reate (and return name of)

`'Form' 'hello world'` a GUI form with appropriate caption

`⊢` yield the form's name while ignoring the result of

`(⎕DL 3)` **D**e**l**aying 3 seconds (the ignored result is the elapsed time)

`⎕EX` **Ex**punge the form (thus making it disappear)

This only works on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

## C (MSVC) + Windows API, <s>130</s> 119

-11 thanks to [@EasyasPi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/94093/easyaspi)

```c
#include<windows.h>
main(){GetProcAddress(LoadLibrary("user32.dll"),"MessageBoxTimeoutA")(0,"Hello World",0,0,0,3000);}
```

Never thought the Windows API could get this short! Many thanks to [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26656324/8828658) for documenting the undocumented `MessageBoxTimeoutA` function.

[image: Message box]

Comment: -11 bytes if you use `main()` instead of `WinMain(..)`, and use `LoadLibrary` instead of `LoadLibraryA`.

Answer (score 1):

## Cobra - 180

```
use System.Windows.Forms
use System.Threading
class M
    def main
        Thread(ref .w).start
        Thread.sleep(3000)
        Environment.exit(0)
    def w
        MessageBox.show("hello world")
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>83</s> 72 bytes

```python
from tkinter import*
f=Tk()
f.wm_title("Hello World")
f.after(3000,exit)
```

Save bytes by using `tkinter`.

The old method added a `Label` to the frame. This method sets the title of the frame to `Hello World`. `f.after(3000,exit)` runs `exit()` after `3000` milliseconds have passed.

Comment: Same idea, different module: `turtle` has less bytes. =D http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28548/14506

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby [with Shoes] (44 chars)

```
Shoes.app{para "Hello world";every(3){exit}}
```

[image: osx app]

Answer (score 1):

## C# 124

Far from the shortest :(

```
class P{static void Main(){new System.Windows.Forms.Form(){Text="Hello World"}.Show();System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);}}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Bash with `xterm`, 34

Uses the title of an `xterm` window to display "Hello World". Does close after 3 seconds.

```bsh
xterm -T Hello\ World -e sleep\ 3
```

If displaying `Hello_World` (without a space) is allowed, you can save one char (`xterm -T Hello_World -e sleep\ 3`).

Comment: I'm curious if you could get this to work with rxvt to shave off a byte.

Answer (score 1):

## Legacy C/Xt/Motif (240)

Super old-school entry!

Link with `-lXm -lXt -lX11`, order matters.

Also curious if this works on other *nix platforms, because the XFlush is me subverting what I'm supposed to do (enter the application loop) in order that I don't have to install a timer to shut down after 3 seconds (and consume more characters).

```
#include <Xm/XmAll.h>
int main(int n,char **v){XtAppContext c;Widget t=XtVaAppInitialize(&c,"h",NULL,0,&n,v,NULL,NULL);XtVaSetValues(t,XmNtitle,"Hello World",XmNminWidth,300,NULL);XtRealizeWidget(t);XFlush(XtDisplay(t));sleep(3);return 0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

### TCL, 52 bytes

```
label .l -text Hello\ World
pack .l
after 3000 exit
```

Comment: You can save bytes if you nest `label` into `pack` as: `pack [label .l -text Hello\ World]`

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (51)

Some old JavaScript methods that still exist because they existed in Netscape 2. `document.write` replaces the page with a string. `setTimeout` calls a function after given time (in miliseconds). `close` closes the window. Doesn't work in Firefox JS console, but it works when imported with `<script>` or in other browsers' JavaScript consoles.

```js
document.write("Hello world")
setTimeout(close,3e3)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Factor, 128 bytes

```
[ f T{ world-attributes { title "" } } clone "Hello world" <label> >>gadgets open-window* 3 seconds sleep close-window ] with-ui
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E) + `Message` permission, 39 bytes

```
'‚«™’ÿ.¬•"ÄÖ/€º:3 * Ÿ™ ‚ï"’.E
```

---

```erl
'‚«™’...’.E  # trimmed program
         .E  # evaluate...
    ’...’    # "ÿ.shell\"msg/time:3 * hello world\""...
             # (implicit) with ÿ replaced by...
'‚«          # "system"...
   ™         # in title case...
         .E  # as Elixir code

====================

System.shell"..."  # trimmed program
System.shell       # execute shell command...
            "..."  # literal

====================

msg/time:3 * ...  # trimmed program
msg               # show message...
             ...  # literal...
   /time:         # that closes after...
         3        # literal...
   /time:         # seconds...
           *      # to all users
```

Comment: if it requires msg.exe, then you need to add that along with the language name.

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby - 136 bytes

Using FXRuby :

```
require'fox16';include Fox;a=FXApp.new;timeout=a.addTimeout(3000)do|s|a.exit;end;a.create;FXMessageBox.error(a,MBOX_OK,'','Hello World')
```

[image: FXRuby]

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript (ECMAScript) + jQuery

**65 Script + 23 Html = 88 Characters**

*Html*

```
<div id='a'>Hello World
```

*Script*

```
e=$('#a'),d='dialog',x=e[d]();setTimeout(B=n=>{x.remove()},3000)
```

*All-in-one* (105 Characters)

`<div id='a'>Hello World<script>e=$('#a'),d='dialog',x=e[d]();setTimeout(B=n=>{x.remove()},3000)</script>`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/9jjPC/)

```
 <div id="a">Hello World
 <script>
   e=$("#a"),
   d='dialog',
   x=e[d]();
   setTimeout(B=n=>{x.remove()},3000)
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

### VB.NET Winforms, 167

```vb
Private Sub Form2_Shown(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    Me.Text = "hello world"
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
    End
End Sub
```

based on ace suggestion the new code is

**NOW 100 Characters**

```
 Sub f() Handles Me.Shown
Me.Text = "hello world"
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
End
End Sub
```

Comment: You can golf it down a lot more. Start by reducing whitespace (e.g. use one space instead of 4 spaces for indentation, remove the spaces between the assignment operator). Try using single character identifiers, e.g. `Sub F(s As Object,e As System.EventArgs)Handles Me.Shown` (not sure whether you can replace `sender`). Try to remove `Private` and see if that works.

Comment: @ace you are correct, the new code is                      Sub f() Handles Me.Shown
        Me.Text = "hello world"
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
        End
    End Sub

Answer (score 0):

## Linux Shell, 54

```
echo "hello world">f;firefox f;sleep 3;killall firefox
```

Comment: I tried "timeout 3 firefox Hello\ world" and it appeared to work, but then the next time I started firefox it reset itself to factory settings.

Answer (score 0):

### HTML/JavaScript (81)

```
<body onload="setTimeout(function(){document.body.innerHTML=''},3e3)">Hello World
```

Answer (score 0):

## Tcl/Tk, 15+11=26

```
after 3000 exit
```

If I name the file "Hello world.tcl", I will automatically get the "Hello world" text as the window's title:

[image]

Comment: Unless you count the file name as part of your score, this violates [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1072/66833) standard loophole.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing: fixed. I added the byte count of the file name without the `.tcl` part

Answer (score 0):

## Vala + `gtk+-3.0`, 144 bytes

```cs
void main(string[]a){Gtk.init(ref a);var w=new Gtk.Window();w.title="hello world";w.show();Timeout.add(3000,()=>{Process.exit(0);});Gtk.main();}
```

First Vala program, first GTK program.

The title is `hello world`, but the default window size causes it to clip on my window manager.

[image]

```cs
void main(string[] args)
{
    // Initialize GTK
    Gtk.init(ref args);
    // Create a new window
    var win = new Gtk.Window();
    // Set the title
    win.title = "hello world";
    // Set the window to show
    win.show();
    // Set a timeout to exit the program after 3 seconds
    Timeout.add(3000, () => { Process.exit(0); });
    // Enter the main GTK loop to show the window
    Gtk.main();
}
```